# How do I get around 'Function components cannot be given refs' when I'm trying to navigate to the home page after sign up with React Navigation 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

I'm currently doing the authentication for my application and I've gotten everything working except for the navigation once the user has logged in. I'm quite new to React Nav 5 and can't seem to get my head around it. I've been following a udemy guide but I think React Nav 4 is being used and I can't seem to find out how to do this, I've supplied my code and the related screenshots below. What I'm trying to do is get to the feed page once the user has clicked the signup button. So far I have gotten the app connected with a backend and to mongoDB which is all working well I just can't navigate to the feed page once the sign up is complete.

App.JS

[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIzOA.png)

navigationRef

[navigationRef screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHGuu.png)

AuthContext

[authContext screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kpww.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the NavRef using the createRef() hook instead,

**navigationRef.js:**

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
    navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

And then, from the App.js, you can use the reference in the NavigationContainer like this,

**App.js:**

```
<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
    <AuthNavigator/>
</NavigationContainer>
```